# how to document insert with the collections in Marklogic using XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a requirement where in I have to insert documents with name 1 to 6 with extension .xml, set the collection as "flags" to each of the documents in one go, and insert them into a directory called America.

How can I achieve this using [`xdmp:document-insert`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a minimal example that inserts the 6 documents and sets the "flags" collection with dummy content `<doc/>`.

```
for $i in (1 to 6)
let $uri := "/America/"||$i||".xml"
return 
  xdmp:document-insert($uri, <doc/>, 
    <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">
      <collections>
        <collection>flags</collection>
      </collections>
    </options>)
```

with the URIs:

- /America/1.xml
- /America/2.xml
- /America/3.xml
- /America/4.xml
- /America/5.xml
- /America/6.xml